# Сравнение двух таблиц и изменение цвета текста строки таблицы

Tags: java, sql, table

Есть 2 таблицы. Sql запросом сравниваю таблицы на совпадающие значения первого столбика и при совпадении нужно закрасить строки первой таблицы зеленым цветом.
Не получается это сделать. Закрашиваются все строки красным.

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

                try {
                    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

                    st=conn.createStatement();
                    sql = "Select DISTINCT id From product Where id In (Select id_product From invoices)";
                    rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
                    int result = 0;   
                    while (rs.next()){
                        result = rs.getInt("id");

                        for (int i = 0; i<table_allProduct.getRowCount();i++){
                        row = (int) table_allProduct.getValueAt(i, 0);}
                        //System.out.print(result+" ");                               
                        if(row == result) {
                            setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                            return this;
                        } else {
                            setForeground(Color.RED);
                        }
                    }                         

                    return this;                
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Success.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. у вас есть заполненная таблица на форме и есть таблица в базе. Судя по коду, вы хотите красить ячейку зеленым, если в ячейке значение совпадает с тем что есть в базе, если нет -- красным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, нет смысла перебирать таблицу на каждую ячейку таблицы, тем более что значение ячейки и ее координаты будут переданы в метод.

Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
 
        // Нас интересует только первый столбец
        if (column != 0) {
            return this;
        }
        
        // Не знаю какое значение в value, но пусть будет Integer
        Integer valueId = (Integer) value;
        boolean has = false;
        
        try {
            st = conn.createStatement();
            sql = "Select DISTINCT id From product Where id In (Select id_product From invoices)";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            
            // Ищем наше значение среди, все из результата запроса
            while (rs.next()) {
                int result = rs.getInt("id");
                
                // Если нашли
                if (valueId == result) {
                    has = true;
                    break;
                }
            }               
            
            // Если has == true, окрашиваешь зеленым, иначе красным
            setForeground(has ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Success.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

Но и предложенный мной вариант не эффективный, т.к. если у нас первый столбец это id таблицы `product`, который также совпадает с значением поля `id_product` таблицы `invoices`, то зачем нам делать запросы на id?

Ведь нам нужно просто проверить что такой `id` существует, а значит тот запрос можно упростить до `sql = "SELECT 1 FROM invoices WHERE id_product = " + valueId;` (чтобы не бояться sql-инъекции, нужно использовать биндинг параметров и `PreparedStatement`, но для этого примера и не зная чем у вас является `conn`, не стал это включать).

Тогда код упростится до:

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
 
        // Нас интересует только первый столбец
        if (column != 0) {
            return this;
        }
        
        // Не знаю какое значение в value, но пусть будет Integer
        Integer valueId = (Integer) value;
        
        try {
            st = conn.createStatement();
            sql = "SELECT 1 FROM invoices WHERE id_product = " + valueId;
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            
            // Если нашли id
            boolean has = rs.next();
            
            // Если has == true, окрашиваешь зеленым, иначе красным
            setForeground(has ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Success.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

**PS.** заметил что у вас создается выражение `st=conn.createStatement();`, но не закрывается `st.close()`, [так лучше не делать](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html#closing_connections). Советую для этого использовать `try-with-resource` выражение.

Пример:

```
...

try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
    sql = "Select DISTINCT id From product Where id In (Select id_product From invoices)";
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

    ...

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Success.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

...
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то что мне нужно. Действительно с запросом можно было не мудрить. Чтобы не бояться sql-инъекции использовать PreparedStatement будет достаточным?

Comment: @ЕленаЧччччччч, да, достаточно

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (int i = 0; i<table_allProduct.getRowCount();i++){
       row = (int) table_allProduct.getValueAt(i, 0);
       //System.out.print(result+" ");                               
       if(row == result) {
           setForeground(Color.GREEN);
           return this;
       } else {
           setForeground(Color.RED);
       }
  }
```

Comment: А чем ваш код кроме форматирования блока отличается от кода в вопросе?

Comment: Понял, в вопросе неправильно фигурная скобка цикла стоит. Лучше описывайте в ответе проблему, а то не сразу догадаешься :)